# Configure spider to ignore url parameters so scrapy doesn't scrape the same page twice

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to configure a Scrapy spider to ignore URL parameters in the visited URLs so that `www.example.com/page?p=value2` won't be visited if `www.example.com/page?p=value1` has been visited already?

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-querycleaner

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't configure it, but as per [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class), you can subclass standard duplicates filter class and override it's `request_fingerprint` method.

This is not tested, but should work. First subclass the standard duplicates filter class (in e.g. `dupefilters.py`):

```
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner
from scrapy.dupefilters import RFPDupeFilter
from scrapy.utils.request import request_fingerprint

class MyRFPDupeFilter(RFPDupeFilter):

    def request_fingerprint(self, request):
        new_request = request.replace(url=url_query_cleaner(request.url))
        return request_fingerprint(new_request)
```

Set `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` to your class in the `settings.py`:

```
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'myproject.dupefilters.MyRFPDupeFilter'
```